# SQL: Selecting all teachers who teach 2 or more courses?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, multi-select

I have a database with the following [ER-diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr5pa.jpg).

I have to write a query that selects all teachers who teach at least 2 courses where the average grades (with range 1-10) differ by at least 1.

To achieve this, I first wanted to try selecting all teachers who teach at least 2 courses in the first place. But so far I have not managed to succeed on this.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT t.teacherid, t.teachername
FROM teacherassignmentstocourseoffers ta 
JOIN teachers t ON t.teacherid = ta.teacherid 
JOIN courseoffers co ON co.courseofferid = ta.courseofferid
GROUP BY t.teacherid, t.teachername
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

However, this does not seem to give the correct teachers. Since I am relatively new to working with databases, I am struggling quite a bit, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the grouping will collapse here to `Teacher, TeacherName` - that will be a group of *one* all the time. You need to include courses in the result - specifically, count() of courses. Your having will then be having `count(course id) >= 2` or something along those lines. As a beginner (or even an experienced developer, including the count of courses in the result is also a good way to check yourself - you want to see that you are counting courses correctly here too, and have the right teachers with that "check figure" included. You might take that out once it's all settled).

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem

```
WITH courseavg(
    SELECT AVG(grade) grade, courseofferid
    FROM courseregistration 
    GROUP BY courseofferid 
)
SELECT MIN(c.grade) mingrade , MAX(c.grade) maxgrade ,t.teacherName, COUNT(tc.teacherid) count 
FROM courseavg c
JOIN teacherassignmentstocourseoffers tc ON tc.courseofferid = c.courseofferid
JOIN teachers t ON t.teacherid = tc.teacherid
GROUP BY tc.teacherid
HAVING count(teacherid) >1 AND  (MAX(c.grade) - MIN(c.grade)) >= 1
```